# Starting and Stopping an InboundChannelAdapter manually

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to start an InboundChannelAdapter manually using a @Scheduled function. I think I'm setting up the message payload wrong but I'm not sure what to have it as. Here's the code:

```
@EnableScheduling
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class KafkaSource {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(Source.OUTPUT)
    private MessageChannel controlBusChannel;

    @Scheduled(cron="0 27 0 * * *", zone="US/Eastern")
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("REACHED");
        Message controlMessage = MessageBuilder.withPayload("@'source.input.inboundChannelAdapter'.start()").build();
        controlBusChannel.send(controlMessage);
    }

    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = Source.OUTPUT, poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "1"), autoStartup = "false") 
    public AgentCreated consumeAndSendMessage() {
         // UNIMPORTANT CODE
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E: Method call: Method transform(java.lang.String) cannot be found on type com.company.transformer.SpecialNotesTransformer$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c10d699d
```

The error occurs at the controlBusChannel.send() line and the transformer in the error is the first one that runs after the source.  How do I frame the message payload properly? The channel is created automatically by the [Source.class](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/main/spring-cloud-stream/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/messaging/Source.java) in Spring Cloud Stream library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an outdated API.

The annotation-based configuration model has been long deprecated in favor of [functional programming model](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.3/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring-cloud-stream-overview-producing-consuming-messages), so `EnableBinding`, `StreamListener` etc are on their way out.

For you case you can simply use Supplier with StreamBridge. See [this section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.3/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_sending_arbitrary_data_to_an_output_e_g_foreign_event_driven_sources) for more details. And then you can do programmatic start/stop binding using the available [lifecycle features](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.3/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#binding_visualization_control) of spring-cloud-stream.

Now, that doesn't mean your other problem will be resolved, but without a full stack trace and sufficient detail (e.g., version of frameworks you are using) it is difficult to say.

Comment: This is super useful for when we upgrade, but in the meantime, we are running spring-boot-starter-parent 1.5.22.RELEASE and spring-cloud-stream 1.3.0.RELEASE, so this wont work. Do you know what to do for that case?

Comment: You are running versions that are no longer supported. That includes stream and boot